# Optimizing queries by creating index(es)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with 20 columns. In the frontend you can filter by interval ranges of these columns, depending on what you want using one column, two or all of them. There're other filters, that come from other table so if using them, I add `inner join` to the query.

I am trying to create indexes to make these queries faster since they take too much time.

I am using this query to find needed indexes:

```sql
SELECT
   CONVERT (varchar, getdate(), 126) AS runtime
   , mig.index_group_handle
   , mid.index_handle
   , CONVERT (decimal (28,1), migs.avg_total_user_cost * migs.avg_user_impact *
        (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans)) AS improvement_measure
   , 'CREATE INDEX missing_index_' + CONVERT (varchar, mig.index_group_handle) + '_' +
        CONVERT (varchar, mid.index_handle) + ' ON ' + mid.statement + '
        (' + ISNULL (mid.equality_columns,'')
        + CASE WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL
        AND mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL
        THEN ',' ELSE '' END + ISNULL (mid.inequality_columns, '') + ')'
        + ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS create_index_statement
   , migs.*
   , mid.database_id
   , mid.[object_id]
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups AS mig
   INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats AS migs
      ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
   INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details AS mid
      ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
 ORDER BY migs.avg_total_user_cost * migs.avg_user_impact * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) DESC
```

but when I apply different filters, I get different indexes suggestions, so basically that I should create indexes for each scenario, which doesn't seem okay.

my example query using lots of filters:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
             (CLV.UserId), CLV.RegistrationDate, NumberOfTransactions, TotalSpend, ProbabilityAlive, 
             DeltaProbabilityAlive, ProbabilityActive, DeltaProbabilityActive, EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLong, 
             DeltaEstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLong, EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsShort,
             DeltaEstimatedNumberOfTransactionsShort, ExpectedMonetaryValue, ResidualLifeTimeValue,
              CustomerLifetimeValue, Rank, Product
             FROM [dbo].[CLV]  INNER JOIN [dbo].[TransactionsDataExtra]
              ON [dbo].[TransactionsDataExtra].[UserId] = [dbo].[CLV].[UserId]
               WHERE  CLV.[CalculationDate] = '3/11/2020 12:00:00 AM' AND
               CLV.[ExpectedMonetaryValue] >= 0 AND  CLV.[ExpectedMonetaryValue] <= 364 AND 
                CLV.[EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLong] >= 0 AND  CLV.[EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLong] 
                <= 1833 AND  CLV.[ClientId] = '2' AND  CLV.[Product] = 'Lithuania' AND  TransactionsDataExtra.[Custom5] IN ('Romania','Bulgaria','Latvia') ORDER BY [dbo].[CLV].[UserId] 
              OFFSET (1 - 1) * 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

could someone give some insights what are the best practices when creating those indexes, how to achieve the best results?

Comment: Required Reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Asking for what is "best practice" is often off topic for Stack Overflow as it generates opinionated answers. If, however, you are asking about Index creation and maintenance, then the question may also be better off on [dba.se]; provided you ensure that it also doesn't create opinionated answers.

Comment: Those missing indexes are suggestions, not recommendations. Consider using the Database Tuning Advisor (SSMS Tools menu) for your specific workload.

Comment: I think you need create index fulltext search and inclued the columns and so create index

Answer (score 1):

> when I apply different filters, I get different indexes suggestions, so basically that I should create indexes for each scenario, which doesn't seem okay.

Either identify the most common query patterns and provide indexes supporting those, or perhaps use a [Nonclustered Columnstore Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) to provide optimized scanning for all the columns in a table.